# CSS div class do not adjust to max-width

Tags: html, css

**Problem:** The code in the `css` stylesheet under `.row` is suppose to center the navigation menu (nav) so it has the same space from left side as the title. However, it doesn't work.

I tried to use the same `css` properties on the `nav` section and that works (*that part is commented out*). I'm also using the `.row` class for the features section further down so need to get it to work, but I haven't found any solutions to it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Underneath is my code:

```css
    /*
    
    Orange color: #e67e22 
    
    */
    
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* Basic setup */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    * {
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    /*    border: 1px solid;*/
    }
    
    html,
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #555;
        font-family: "Lato", "Arial", "sans-serif";
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }
    
    }
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    .row { /* SITE DOESNT ADDJUST TO ROW; WORKS WITH NAV */
        max-width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    nav{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
    }
    
    section {
        padding: 80px 0;
    }
    
    .box {
        padding: 1%;
    }
    
    /* ---------HEADINGS-------- */
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    h1 { /* H1 doesnt adjust according to relative font-size, nor margins */
        font-size: 240%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        word-spacing: 4px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 180%;
        word-spacing: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2:after {
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #e67e22;
        content: " ";
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 110%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        
    }
    
    /* ---------PARAGRAPHS-------- */
    .long-copy {
        line-height: 145%;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 15%;
    }
    .box p {
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 145%;
    }
    
    /* ---------ICONS-------- */
    .icon-big {
        font-size: 350%;
        display: block;
        color: #e67e22;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
    }
    
    /* ---------BUTTONS-------- */
    
    .btn:link,
    .btn:visited {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 200px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }
    
    .btn-full:link,
    .btn-full:visited { 
        background-color: #e67e22;
        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    
    .btn-ghost:link,
    .btn-ghost:visited {
        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #e67e22;
    }
    
    .btn:hover,
    .btn:active {
        background-color: #cf6d17;
    }
    
    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active { 
        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .btn-ghost:hover,
    .btn-ghost:active {
        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* HEADER */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    header {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)), url(img/hero.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .hero-textbox{
        position: absolute;
        width: 1140px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 90%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        transition: border-bottom 0,2;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a:hover,
    .main-nav li a:active {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 90%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
        <title>Omnifood</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo"class="logo">
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Food delivery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="hero-textbox">
                <h1>Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I’m hungry</a>
                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <section class="section-features">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food</h2>
                <p class="long-copy">
                Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-infinite-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                    <p>
                    Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-stopwatch-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                    <p>
                    You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-3-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-nutrition-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>100% organic</h3>
                    <p>
                    All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-4-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-cart-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Order anything</h3>
                    <p>
                    We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - extra }, closing `html,body`

```css
/*
    
    Orange color: #e67e22 
    
    */
    
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* Basic setup */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    * {
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    /*    border: 1px solid;*/
    }
    
    html,
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #555;
        font-family: "Lato", "Arial", "sans-serif";
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    .row { /* SITE DOESNT ADDJUST TO ROW; WORKS WITH NAV */
        max-width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    nav{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1140px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
    }
    
    section {
        padding: 80px 0;
    }
    
    .box {
        padding: 1%;
    }
    
    /* ---------HEADINGS-------- */
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    h1 { /* H1 doesnt adjust according to relative font-size, nor margins */
        font-size: 240%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        word-spacing: 4px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 180%;
        word-spacing: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2:after {
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #e67e22;
        content: " ";
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 110%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        
    }
    
    /* ---------PARAGRAPHS-------- */
    .long-copy {
        line-height: 145%;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 15%;
    }
    .box p {
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 145%;
    }
    
    /* ---------ICONS-------- */
    .icon-big {
        font-size: 350%;
        display: block;
        color: #e67e22;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
    }
    
    /* ---------BUTTONS-------- */
    
    .btn:link,
    .btn:visited {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 200px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }
    
    .btn-full:link,
    .btn-full:visited { 
        background-color: #e67e22;
        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    
    .btn-ghost:link,
    .btn-ghost:visited {
        border: 1px solid #e67e22;
        color: #e67e22;
    }
    
    .btn:hover,
    .btn:active {
        background-color: #cf6d17;
    }
    
    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active { 
        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .btn-ghost:hover,
    .btn-ghost:active {
        border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    /* HEADER */
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    
    header {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)), url(img/hero.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .hero-textbox{
        position: absolute;
        width: 1140px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 90%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        transition: border-bottom 0,2;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a:hover,
    .main-nav li a:active {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 90%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
        <title>Omnifood</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo"class="logo">
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Food delivery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="hero-textbox">
                <h1>Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I’m hungry</a>
                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <section class="section-features">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food</h2>
                <p class="long-copy">
                Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-infinite-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                    <p>
                    Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-stopwatch-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                    <p>
                    You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-3-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-nutrition-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>100% organic</h3>
                    <p>
                    All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-4-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-cart-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Order anything</h3>
                    <p>
                    We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi there just change the style of .row like this :

```
.row {
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;

    text-align: center;

    display: inline-grid;

    margin-top: -147px;

    right: 70px;
}
```